# calculate angle from vector to coord

Tags: math, vector, formula, angle, algebra

I am breaking my head trying to find an appropriate formula to calculate a what sounds to be an easy task but in practice is a big mathematical headache.

I want to find out the offset it needs to turn my vector's angle (X, Y, Angle) to face a coord ( X, Y )

[image]

My vector won't always be facing 360 degrees, so i need that as a variable as well..
Hoping an answer before i'm breaking my pc screen.
Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input

- `p1 = (x1,y1)` point1 (vector origin)
- `p2 = (x2,y2)` point2
- `a1 = 360 deg` direction of vector
- assuming your coodinate system is: X+ is right Y+ is up ang+ is CCW
- your image suggest that you have X,Y mixed up (angle usually start from X axis not Y)
- `da=?` change of a1 to match direction of `p2-p1`

solution 1:

- `da=a1-a2=a1-atanxy(x2-x1,y1-y1)`
- atanxy(dx,dy) is also called atan2 on some libs just make sure the order of operands is the right one
- you can also use mine [atanxy in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214)
- it is 4 quadrant arctangens

solution 2:

- `v1=(cos(a1),sin(a1))`
- `v2=(x2-x1,y2-y1)`
- `da=acos(dot(v1,v2)/(|v1|*|v2|))`

or the same slightly different

- `v1=(cos(a1),sin(a1))`
- `v2=(x2-x1,y2-y1)`
- `v2/=|v2|` // makes v2 unit vector, v1 is already unit
- `da=acos(dot(v1,v2))`

so:

```
da=acos((cos(a1)*(x2-x1)+sin(a1)*(y2-y1)/sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
```

[notes]

- just change it to match your coordinate system (which you did not specify)
- use radians or degrees according to your sin,cos,atan dependencies ...

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the vectors is also a vector.

Then calculate the tangens (y part / x part) and invert it to an angle.

Of course use the sign of y if x = 0.

Answer (score 0):

if the coord to face is (x2 ,y2)

deltaY = y2 - y1

deltaX = x2 - x1

You have the angle in degrees between the two points using this formula...

angleInDegrees = arctan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / PI

subtract the original angle of your vector and you will get the correct offset!