# Trace a shape into a polygon of max n sides

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm that will find an irregular shape, maybe not too irregular, like a squashed circle, on a surface, and trace a polygon of a maximum of n sides around the shape. The 'n' maximimum might be based on the area of the shape.

Comment: what is the input data? point set, polygon, raster image? what is desired accuracy ? is it matching against table of shapes or just need to find shape? what do you mean by shape closed area/polygon or feature on surface? what space ? 2D,3D,N-D ? add example images of input and output

Comment: The input data will be basically irregular oval shaped blobs, such as a young child would outline things with. Just need to reduce the set of points on the perimeter into a set of triangles that can define an approximation of the blob. 2D space.

Comment: and the input is vector or raster and how many dimensions ???!!!

Comment: The output is vector and in 2 dimensions - a polygon - e.g. if the input was a circle, and the maximum sides was 8, the output would be an octagon.

Comment: in that case check my answer if it is what you need/want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. **compute tangent angles `ang` and its change `dang` for all curve segments**

   you can use [atanxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214) or `atan2` for that

   ```
   ang[i] = atanxy(x[i]-x[i-1],y[i]-y[i-1]);
   dang[i] = ang[i]-ang[i-1];
   ```
2. **find inflex points (Black)**

   at these points the sign of `dang` is changing so

   ```
   dang[i-1]*dang[i+1]<0.0
   ```

   but you need to handle the `dang=0.0` elements properly (need to scan before and after them). These points will be the fundamental skeleton for your output polygon
3. **add the bumps max points (green)**

   at these points the tangent angle is between nearest inflex points so to find max point between two inflex points `i0` and `i1` find the closest angle to

   ```
   angavg=0.5*(ang[i0]+ang[i1])
   ```

   do not forget that

   ```
   |ang[i]-angavg|<=PI
   ```

   so `+/- 2.0*PI` if this is not true
4. **now you should have all significant points of your closed polycurve ...**

   it should look like this:

   [image: img]

   **CW/CCW** or Red/Blue just represents the sign of `dang[i]` ...

**[Notes]**

The output point type should be preserved (inflex/maxpoint) because it can be later used for comparison and detection of shapes ...

Comment: plus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer–Douglas–Peucker_algorithm for line simplification if needed