# Sampling methods for plotting

Tags: algorithm, plot, graphics, sampling

Say we are making a program to render the plot of a function (black box) provided by the user as a sequence of line segments. We want to get the minimum number of samples of the function so the resulting image "looks" like the function (the exact meaning of "looks" here is part of the question). A naive approach might be to just sample at fixed intervals but we can probably do better than that eg by sampling the "curvy bits" more than the "linear bits". Are there systematic approaches/research on this problem?

Comment: If you can get the derivative of the function, you can sample more when the derivative is high because that means it's changing faster.

Comment: It reminds me of [approxPolyDP](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#approxpolydp) from opencv. Under the hood it runs [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) maybe it fits your usecase ?

Comment: Random sampling is a good idea if your function has periodic behaviors.  For instance, sparse (low frequency) sampling can make a sine/cosine look like it has a much lower frequency than it actually has.  See https://medium.com/@technicalsource9/what-happens-to-sounds-above-the-nyquist-frequency-in-digital-audio-60b0bb5c66f7 for a nice graphic illustrating this.

Comment: see [Trace a shape into a polygon of max n sides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299761/2521214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [reference](https://ojs.cvut.cz/ojs/index.php/gi/article/download/gi.17.2.2/4751) can be helpful which is using the combined sampling method. Before that its related works explain more about other methods of sampling:

> There are several strategies for plotting the function y = f(x) on interval Ω = [a, b]. The
>   naive approach based on sampling of f in a fixed amount of the equally spaced points is
>   described in [[20]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1009950630139). The simple functions suffer from oversampling, while the oscillating curves
>   are under-sampled; these issues are mentioned in [[14]](https://doi.org/10.1145/143242.143314). Another approach based on the interval
>   constraint **plot constructing a hull of the curve** was described in [[6]](https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/S0743-1066(96)00142-2), [[13]](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1009705709733), [[20]](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1009950630139). The **automated
>   detection of a useful domain and a range of the function** is mentioned in [41]; the **generalized
>   interval arithmetic approach** is described in [40].
>
> A significant refinement is represented by **adaptive sampling** providing a higher sampling
>   density in the higher-curvature regions. The are several algorithms for the curve interpolation preserving the speed, for example: [37], [[42]](https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(94)90045-0), [43]. The adaptive feed rate technique
>   is described in [44]. An early implementation in the Mathematica software is presented in
>   [[39]](https://books.google.cz/books?id=l%5C_MYAQAAIAAJ). By reducing data, these methods are very efficient for the curve plotting. The polygonal approximation of the parametric curve based on adaptive sampling is mentioned in the
>   several papers. The refinement criteria, as well as the recursive approach, are discussed in
>   [15]. An approximation by the polygonal curves is described in [7], the robust method for
>   the geometric and spatial approximation of the implicit curves can be found in [27], [10], the
>   affine arithmetic working in the triangulated models in [32]. However, the map projections
>   are never defined by the implicit equations. Similar approaches can be used for graph drawing
>   [21].
>   Other techniques based on the **approximation by the breakpoints** can be found in many
>   papers: [33], [9], [3]; these approaches are used for the polygonal approximation of the closed
>   curves and applied in computer vision.

Hence, these are the reference methods that define some measures for a "good" plot and introduce an approach to optimize the plot base on the measure:

- constructing a hull of the curve
- automated detection of a useful domain and a range of the function
- adaptive sampling: providing a higher sampling density in the higher-curvature regions
- providing a higher sampling density in the higher-curvature regions
- approximation by the polygonal curves
- affine arithmetic working in the triangulated models
- combined sampling: providing the polygonal approximation of the parametric curve involving the discontinuities will be presented. The modified method will be used for the function f(x) reconstruction and plot. Based on the ideas of splitting the domain into the subintervals without the discontinuities, it represents a typical problem solvable by the recursive approach.