# I need an equation for equal movement along an ellipse

Tags: objective-c, math, swift

i am programing something like planets moving around the Sun, and to move planets i am using a function

```
CGPointMake(object.center.x + 1, sqrt(75*75*150*150 - 75*75*(object.center.x - 300)*(object.center.x - 300))/150 + 150)
```

using elliptic equation where a = 150, b = 75, p = 300, q = 150, but when object closes to x = around 450 its speed rises, i guess that is because of pithagoras because the path its passes is c = sqrt((x-x0)^2*(y-y0)^2)

i notice my c is always around 0.5, but when it gets on the end of x domain it rises up to 0.8 so i need either a programatic or mathematical solution to make object move at same speed around an elliptic curve.

Comment: This is probably more a math or physics question. But as far as I know, planets to *not* move with constant speed on their elliptic orbit.

Comment: i know that, but i either need a equation for real planet movement, or solution to the problem above, becouse like this it looks very unreal

Comment: i can solve this by lowering x incerement when object is in x: 150 - 170 range, couse that is where c increases, but that is very bad programing i guess

Comment: @JosipBogdan edited my answer. btw it looks like it works even if the `rx<=ry` (but not sure if in all circumstances ... the only thing that could go wrong is perimeter computation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you want the real thing**

then the planets closer to the primary focus point  (center of mass of stellar system ... **very close** to star) are moving faster so use [**Kepler's equation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) here: [C++ implementation of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722336/2521214). Do not forget to check out all the sub-links in that answer you can find there everything you need.

**If you want constant speed instead**

Then use parametric ellipse equation

```
x(a)=x0+rx*cos(a)
y(a)=y0+ry*sin(a)
```

where `a` is angle `<0,2.0*PI>` `(x0,y0)` is the ellipse center and `(rx,ry)` are the ellipse semi axises (radii).

if `a` is incremented with constant speed then the area increase is constant so the `a` is the mean circular angle not the visual on ellipse !!! For more info look here:

- [Issue with ellipse angle calculation and point calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26422533/2521214)

**[edit1] as  MartinR pointed out the speed is not constant**

so here is approximation with his formula for speed. Ellipse is axis aligned defined by `x0,y0,rx,ry` `(rx>=ry)` the perimeter aproximation `l`:

```
h=(rx-ry)/(rx+ry); h*=3.0*h; l=M_PI*(rx+ry)*(1.0+(h/(10.0+sqrt(4.0-h))));
```

if you want to have `n` chunks of equal sized steps along the perimeter then

```
l/=n;
```

initial computations:

```cpp
double x0,y0,rx,ry,n,l,h;
x0=Form1->ClientWidth>>1;  // center is centered on form
y0=Form1->ClientHeight>>1;
rx=200; // semiaxises rx>=ry !!!
ry=75;
n=40.0; // number of chunks per ellipse (1/speed)
//l=2.0*M_PI*sqrt(0.5*((rx*rx)+(ry*ry)));  // not accurate enough
h=(rx-ry)/(rx+ry); h*=3.0*h; l=M_PI*(rx+ry)*(1.0+(h/(10.0+sqrt(4.0-h)))); // this is more precise
l/=n; // single step size in units,pixels,or whatever
```

first the slow bruteforce attack (black):

```cpp
int i;
double a,da,x,y,xx,yy,ll;
a=0.0;
x=x0+rx*cos(a);
y=y0+ry*sin(a);
for (i=n;i>0;i--)
    {
    xx=x; yy=y;
    for (da=a;;)
        {
        a+=0.001;
        x=x0+rx*cos(a);
        y=y0+ry*sin(a);
        ll=sqrt(((xx-x)*(xx-x))+((yy-y)*(yy-y)));
        if (ll>=l) break;
        } da=a-da;
    scr->MoveTo(5.0+50.0*a,5.0);
    scr->LineTo(5.0+50.0*a,5.0+300.0*da);

    scr->MoveTo(x0,y0);
    scr->LineTo(xx,yy);
    scr->LineTo(x ,y );
    ll=sqrt(((xx-x)*(xx-x))+((yy-y)*(yy-y)));
    scr->TextOutA(0.5*(x+xx)+20.0*cos(a),0.5*(y+yy)+20.0*sin(a),floor(ll));
    }
```

Now the approximation (Blue):

```cpp
a=0.0; da=0;
x=x0+rx*cos(a);
y=y0+ry*sin(a);
for (i=n;i>0;i--)
    {
    scr->MoveTo(5.0+50.0*a,5.0+300.0*da);
    xx=rx*sin(a);
    yy=ry*cos(a);
    da=l/sqrt((xx*xx)+(yy*yy)); a+=da;
    scr->LineTo(5.0+50.0*a,5.0+300.0*da);

    xx=x; yy=y;
    x=x0+rx*cos(a);
    y=y0+ry*sin(a);

    scr->MoveTo(x0,y0);
    scr->LineTo(xx,yy);
    scr->LineTo(x ,y );
    ll=sqrt(((xx-x)*(xx-x))+((yy-y)*(yy-y)));
    scr->TextOutA(0.5*(x+xx)+40.0*cos(a),0.5*(y+yy)+40.0*sin(a),floor(ll));
    }
```

This is clean ellipse step (no debug draws)

```cpp
a=???; // some initial angle
// point on ellipse 
x=x0+rx*cos(a);
y=y0+ry*sin(a);
// next angle by almost constant speed
xx=rx*sin(a);
yy=ry*cos(a);
da=l/sqrt((xx*xx)+(yy*yy)); a+=da;
// next point on ellipse ...
x=x0+rx*cos(a);
y=y0+ry*sin(a);
```

Here the output of comparison bruteforce and approximation:

[image: this is how the result looks like]

**[edit2] little precision boost**

```cpp
 a,da=???; // some initial angle and step (last)
 x=x0+rx*cos(a);
 y=y0+ry*sin(a);
 // next angle by almost constant speed
 xx=rx*sin(a+0.5*da); // use half step angle for aproximation ....
 yy=ry*cos(a+0.5*da);
 da=l/sqrt((xx*xx)+(yy*yy)); a+=da;
 // next point on ellipse ...
 x=x0+rx*cos(a);
 y=y0+ry*sin(a);
```

[image: much closer to bruteforce attack]

the half step angle in approximation lead to much closer result to bruteforce attack

Comment: Is your statement about the constant speed really true? The speed is `sqrt(rx^2 * sin^2(a(t)) + ry^2 * cos^2(a(t))) * a'(t)`, and that is not constant even if `a'(t)` is constant (only for the special case of a circle).

Comment: @MartinR ow youre right it is the area that is constant not the arclength

Comment: @MartinR your equation works added [edit1] to my answer ... the precision of perimeter computation affects this greatly so for high eccentricity is this not very precise.

Comment: this looks great, sry for not checking it sooner, thank u so much, ive been working on this for a week myself but this solutin is what I needed, real deal, id very much like to buy u a beer

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

You could **fake** something like this very easily with SpriteKit. N.B. your entire app doesn't have to use SpriteKit. You can fairly easily put an SKView into a non-SpriteKit app.

Anyway...

Create your planet...

```
SKSpritNode *planet = [SKSpritNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mars"];
[solarSystemView addChild:planet];
```

Create your elliptical path...

```
UIBezierPath *ellipse = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:/*your rect*/]; //or create it any other way.
```

Create an action...

```
SKAction *singleOrbit = [SKAction followPath:ellipse.CGPath speed:10];
SKAction *orbit = [SKAction repeatActionForever:singleOrbit];
```

Run the action...

```
[planet runAction:orbit];
```

Answer (score -2):

In the article "Kinematics of an ellipse", formulas for the movement of a point along an ellipse are presented: 1. uniform, 2. uniformly accelerated, 3. elliptical (Keplerian). It is shown that only when moving 3 Kepler's laws are satisfied https://www.academia.edu/94295697/Ellipse_kinematics