# Trying to find out n equi-spaced points on the boundary of an an ellipse when starting point is given

Tags: c, for-loop, trigonometry, computational-geometry, ellipse

> I have to find out n equi-spaced points on boundary of an ellipse when a (semimajor axis) and b (semiminor axis) are given.
> Starting point is considered as (a, 0). The formula given in code is used to find out such points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.142

 int main()
 {
     int n, i, a, b;
     double dt, x[20], y[20];

   printf("Enter semimajor axis:- ");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("Enter semiminor axis:- ");
   scanf("%d", &b);

   printf("Enter no of points to be equi-spaced:- ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   //Starting point is:- (a, 0). So x[0] = a and y[0] = 0
   x[0] = a;
   y[0] = 0;

   dt = (2*PI)/n;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
        x[i+1] = x[i]*cos(dt) - (a/b)*y[i]*sin(dt);
        y[i+1] = (b/a)*x[i]*sin(dt) + y[i]*cos(dt);
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
       printf("%lf, %lf\n", x[i], y[i]);
  }
 }
```

**Input:-**
Enter semimajor axis:- 4\n
Enter semiminor axis:- 3\n
Enter no of points to be equi-spaced:- 4

**Output:-**
4.000000, 0.000000\n
-0.000815, 0.000000\n
0.000000, -0.000000\n
-0.000000, 0.000000

**This is not expected output.**

Comment: Don't define your own pi.  You're already including math.h, so just use `M_PI`, which is far more accurate.  (I'm not sure if `M_PI` is available on all implementations, but it should be available in gcc.)

Comment: Integer division such as your `(a/b)` truncates towards 0 to the nearest integer.

Comment: You might as well declare `a` and `b` as type `double` and use `scanf("%lf", &a);` to read `a` as a `double`, and do the same for `b`. If you really must declare `a` and `b` as integers, you will need to use `((double)a/b)` and `((double)b/a)` to calculate the fractions.

Comment: see [OpenGL Ellipse with start/end angle issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71219436/2521214) especially `[Edit2] Fast analytic O(1) solution` for some inspiration