# Signed Rotation between two normals in 3D

Tags: math, geometry

Given a plane(in my case a triangle) normal N_T and a reference Normal N_R, both have the length 1.

I calculated the rotation_normal

```
N = N_T x N_R
```

and now i need to calculate the angle around this rotation_normal, which i get with the following calculation:

```
angle = acos(<N_T, N_R>), with <x,y> is the dotproduct of x and y
```

This angle is in the interval of [0°, 180°] and is the smallest angle between both normals. 
So my problem is that if i want to rotate my triangle in a manner that its normal is equal to the reference normal, i need to know in which direction (positive or negative) the calculated angle is.

Does anybody know how to get this direction or how to solve this problem in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use atan2 (4-quadrant arc tangens)

[image: 3D]
[image: 2D reference plane slice]

1. create reference plane basis vectors `u,v`

   - must be perpendicular to each other and lie inside plane
   - preferably unit vectors (or else you need to account for its size)
   - so let `N=N_T x N_R;` ... reference plane normal where the rotation will take place
   - `U=N_T;`
   - `V= N x U;` ... `x` means cross product
   - make them unit `U/=|U|; V/=|V|;` if they are not already
2. compute plane coordinates of `N_R`

   - `u=(N_R.U);` ... `.` means dot product
   - `v=(N_R.V);`
3. compute angle

   - `ang=atan2(v,u);`
   - if you do not have `atan2` then use `ang=`[atanxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214)`(u,v);`
   - this will give you angle in range `ang=<0,2*M_PI>`
   - if you want signed angle instead then add
   - `if (ang>M_PI) ang-=2.0*M_PI;` ... `M_PI` is well known constant `Pi=3.1415...`
   - now if you want the opposite sign direction then just use `-ang`

Comment: thanks, i will verify it in the future when i have time for this

Comment: @m47h when I drawed an image  have found a small bug in the computation have repaired it so check it now (`N` was missing)

Comment: @m47h glad to be of help