# De-skew characters in binary image

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, skew

I'm working on number plate recognition. The problem is that I have to de-skew the characters in a binary image to increase the accuracy of template matching.

I have done a lot of pre-processing to remove unnecessary pixels of the image and I could segment the characters out. But unfortunately they are skewed.

From... converting to greyscale to binary

[image]

Then.. pre-processing techniques..

[image]

After segmentation..

[image]

As can be observed in the last image, the characters are skewed and this will lead to inaccuracy for template matching to perform recognition purposes.

Most of the researchers are using Hough transform to perform the de-skew operation but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to deal with this. Some on the matching part to avoid the **unskew** operation itself like this:

- [OCR and character similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214)

But you want to **unskew** so:

1. **detect the rotation angle/skew slope**

   Obtain bounding box, then cast vertical scan lines and remember first hit point and last regress line through all of them

   [image: algo overview]
2. **rotate/skew back by it**

   So either use `atan2` to obtain the angle or directly construct 2D homogenous 3x3 transform matrix based on basis vectors (one is the line and second is its perpendicular vector). For more info see:

   - [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)
3. **Now the rotated/unskew image will be still skewed bud in much much lower rate**

   so you can apply **#1,#2** in the horizontal axis too but this time you need to **unskew** only (do not use rotation). Usually the remnant skew ratio is small so this step is not necessary.

**[notes]**

You can boost the precision by filtering out wrong points or by carefully selecting the start point of scan lines so they hit in the right place of characters (you obviously know the characters count).

**[edit1] small example**

Here small example of output for your image (Negative as my functions are expecting white paper and black font):

[image: example]

As you can see the rotation and skew is much much smaller.

Comment: isn't rotation of image and performing de-skew is different? @Spektre

Comment: @WongWengkeong yes deskew shifts the points along single axis rotation changes booth x and y

Comment: so.. if im about to use imrotate function will it resolve the skewness of the characters if i consists of the right angle from your solution? @Spektre

Comment: @WongWengkeong That depends on the image if the distortion is due to rotation between car and camera FOV then yes (but you need to restore all rotations not just one in xy plane) if it is caused by something else like taking the picture on the run (each image line is scanned in different time so it is shifted by movement speed) then only partially. In anyway if you restore the biggest rotation/skew then the rest should be distorted only slightly so in most cases you can ignore it (unless you compare characters by comparing pixels directly)

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. currently i have developed your solution and now I have 4 points of coordinates (2 equation line).. i am trying to get the theta for it. I am trying to use atan2 but i dont seem to get the accurate angle. do you mind to show me how to do it? im so sorry for asking so much questions btw @Spektre

Comment: @WongWengkeong 1. visually draw your found points to see if they are correct 2. `atan2` is OK but I use [atanxy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214) instead anyway just be sure if your angle is in radians or degrees and if you provide correct order of operands 3. you can use [line regression/fitting in 2D](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20888844/2521214) or compute the line slope directly from point pairs and selecting the most ocurent slope (this should eliminate the wrong points)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the rotation angle of your skewed black and white data also by [principal component analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) of a set of points consisting of all white pixels in your image.

Here is the code:

```
% load image
img = imread('skewed.png');
img = img(:, :, 1);
img = double(img);

% perform pca on cloud of white points
[r, c] = find(img);
coeff = pca([r,c]);
angle = atan2(coeff(1,1), coeff(1,2));

% rotate back
img = imrotate(img, angle / pi * 180);
imwrite(img > 0, 'deskewed.png');
```

Input:

[image]

Output (rotation angle ~10.3 deg):

[image]