# How to transform a FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) into a Polar Transformation with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, opencv

I was able to create a FFT Transformation from my image but I don't know how to continue...

I am using this to solve my problem: [Align text for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698068/align-text-for-ocr)

This code was all that worked for me until now:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

img = cv2.imread(r'test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20 * np.log(np.abs(fshift))

plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

I need the mean value generated from a Polar Transformation, but I don't know how to transform a **FFT** to a **Polar Transformation** in **Python**.

Comment: What are the mathematics behind the transformation? Are you simply hung up on creating the polar Axes, or is there some mathematical step you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is roughly solution to you problem; It was tested on one sample image, and the result looks credible.

```
# your code goes here... 

def transform_data(m):
    dpix, dpiy = m.shape
    x_c, y_c = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(m), m.shape)
    angles = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, min(dpix, dpiy))
    mrc = min(abs(x_c - dpix), abs(y_c - dpiy), x_c, y_c)
    radiuses = np.linspace(0, mrc, max(dpix, dpiy))
    A, R = np.meshgrid(angles, radiuses)
    X = R * np.cos(A)
    Y = R * np.sin(A)
    return A, R, m[X.astype(int) + mrc - 1, Y.astype(int) + mrc - 1]

    angles, radiuses, m = transform_data(magnitude_spectrum)

    plt.contourf(angles, radiuses, m)
```

[image]

Finally, we can get the angle we want to turn the original image:

```
sample_angles = np.linspace(0,  2 * np.pi, len(c.sum(axis=0))) / np.pi*180
turn_angle_in_degrees = 90 - sample_angles[np.argmax(c.sum(axis=0))]
```

For my sample image I got:

```
turn_angle_in_degrees = 3.2015810276679844 degrees.
```

Also, we can plot projected spectrum magnitude:

```
plt.plot(sample_angles, c.sum(axis=0))
```

[image]

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for help me @bubble! I have just one more question.

Whats is the '**c**' variable used in: **c**.sum(axis=0)

Comment: This is columnwise projection of transformed polar fft. We search for max value of c.sum(axis=0) and get corresponding angle value as was stated in the post you cited above.