# Can't get tesseract settings right

Tags: image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract on this image:

[image]

When I use default configuration:

```
tesseract image.jpg stdout
```

It returns `\KD FWOW`.
As you can see, the only mistake is the first letter `L` being recognized as a backslash

So, I created a config file in `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/configs` with the setting:

`tessedit_char_whitelist ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ`

The goal is to recognize just letters, not special characters. However, when I run tesseract with this config:

```
tesseract image.jpg stdout letters
```

The result is `XKD FVOIV`, and now it is missing more than one character, mainly the 'W'.

This makes no sense to me, I cant figure why it stopped to recognize the W when it is on the whitelist. For sure I am missing something in the config.

How can I fix it?

Comment: why not rectangularize the image first ... that is called preprocessing ... without proper preparation of data it is any CV operation useless ...

Comment: The image was prepared to this point, but I am not using OpenCV, I am using imagemagick

Comment: That does not matter I do not use OpenCV either... find the skew from left and right ... and transform back to rectangular bounding box. similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30273878/2521214