# 2D polylines registration (alignment) algorithm

Tags: geometry, pattern-matching, 2d

I have several polylines (defined by set of points) from two sources - see rendered image where polylines from one source are white and purple from the other.

[image]

The two parts can be aligned together, however I dont know what algorithm to use.

I have tried to use ICP (Iterative closest point), but the problem is that lines are too far away. I have tried to create modification - instead of directly use the closest points use closest points around similar angles. However, to detect similar angles is not working, since the lines are not same - some sharp angles on one are smooth on the other.

Dou you have any idea what how to align the sets? There is no scale in data, only translation (mainly) and a slight rotation (+- 20 degrees)

Raw data for polylines. There are multiple polylines, each of them is separated by `===`

Format:

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
...
```

Purple:

```
3237 253
3652 425
=====
2272 258
2384 409
2560 545
2730 637
2837 814
2882 942
2891 1069
2837 1221
2770 1323
2597 1462
2563 1537
2566 1590
2591 1645
2686 1721
2778 1740
3013 1707
3102 1709
3276 1887
3648 2127
3722 2212
3764 2295
3869 2437
3950 2515
3995 2538
4166 2559
4484 2280
4534 2255
4555 2260
4593 2382
4664 2491
4703 2671
4738 2754
4811 2862
4906 2935
4991 2942
5196 2877
5342 2869
5545 2782
5715 2808
5869 2810
5992 2832
6105 2891
6369 3082
6583 3116
6526 3203
6465 3242
6366 3340
6192 3414
5922 3457
5732 3576
5732 3618
5815 3727
5871 3833
5968 3921
6029 3944
6034 4000
6015 4043
5687 4191
4672 4806
4562 4838
3258 5475
3166 6035
3135 6398
3152 6425
=====
6584 3115
6745 3059
6802 3054
6979 3053
7129 3089
=====
7344 3139
7299 3158
7269 3150
=====
6900 3306
6756 3397
6756 3436
=====
7378 3441
7345 3474
7237 3513
=====
7205 3512
7168 3544
7079 3578
7060 3603
=====
7269 3580
7216 3601
7180 3701
=====
7190 3649
7057 3648
6984 3678
=====
7040 3578
7019 3607
6915 3653
6899 3679
=====
6876 3658
6857 3682
6741 3734
6726 3758
=====
6293 3755
6186 3833
6042 3901
=====
6551 3798
6536 3822
6400 3893
=====
6539 3862
6442 4793
=====
6372 3879
6217 3970
=====
6200 3948
6056 4046
=====
6036 4078
6013 4615
=====
7294 3867
7245 4069
7237 4346
=====
```

White

```
235 1853
485 2032
600 2091
682 2183
813 2414
914 2493
1051 2513
1390 2214
1421 2201
1495 2222
1522 2261
1541 2363
1609 2460
1680 2718
1750 2827
1830 2884
1917 2881
2091 2825
2223 2819
2399 2737
2489 2732
2895 2782
3080 2878
3193 2973
3301 3032
3426 3042
3614 3000
3890 2980
4027 3029
4073 3062
4089 3097
4082 3168
3788 3130
3660 3139
3548 3195
3409 3299
3307 3404
3112 3489
2860 3520
2732 3590
2720 3611
2728 3641
2796 3772
2907 3871
2903 3900
=====
2908 3871
2968 3882
2984 3928
2991 3992
2954 4087
2638 4224
2203 4503
1588 4863
1479 4895
1184 5035
252 5489
235 5518
=====
235 1912
257 1964
228 2035
=====
258 1962
332 1963
=====
2152 4342
2038 4436
1872 4528
=====
1795 4616
1818 4568
1881 4574
=====
1441 4864
1303 4904
927 5098
831 5141
767 5152
=====
597 5017
669 4938
692 4942
=====
838 4944
802 4981
855 5057
904 5054
=====
843 5043
786 5062
795 5084
=====
784 5063
732 5034
641 5086
637 5132
=====
640 5086
581 5084
550 5107
585 5207
=====
742 5031
760 4997
799 4981
=====
1554 4604
1427 4654
=====
1140 4622
1133 4647
1287 4669
1428 4634
=====
```

Comment: @Spektre It is a pointcloud, however, with ordering and therefore points can be connected to create polyline. Scale is the same for both curves.

Comment: @Spektre I have added polylines data

Comment: @Spektre It is separation of polylines

Comment: I figured that much on my own already. I added simple C++ example of what I had in mind ...

Answer (score 1):

Is it pointcloud or polyline?

Is the sampling,scale the same for both curves?

You can use this [How to compare two shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22166032/2521214) and find parts where the sequence of angles is the "same". this is invariant on rotation,scaling and translation. So it should lead to direct match which points from one curve match to which points on the other in order.

In case your polylines do not match exactly you can use [correlation coefficient](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Statistics2/correlation.htm) on the angles or threshold the sum of differences of the angles/number of angles.

In case your order of points might be in reverse between the polylines you need to check both combinations...

After that its just a matter of computing:

1. **scale**

   just by dividing sizes between 2 distant points (forming big line) on both curves
   [image: big lines]
2. **rotation**

   use `atan2` on the same lines from **#1** and substract the angles
3. **translation**

   just substract single point from both curves (but after applying scale and rotation on the point belonging to curve which is being aligned).

Or you can use [transform matrix approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52163563/2521214) instead.

**Here small simple C++/GL/VCL example of brute force search:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
#include "OpenGLrep4d_double.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define polysep -1.1e10,-1.1e10
#define polyend +1.1e10,+1.1e10
double pol0[]=
    {
    3237,253 ,3652,425 ,polysep,2272,258 ,2384,409 ,2560,545 ,2730,637 ,2837,814 ,
    2882,942 ,2891,1069,2837,1221,2770,1323,2597,1462,2563,1537,2566,1590,2591,1645,
    2686,1721,2778,1740,3013,1707,3102,1709,3276,1887,3648,2127,3722,2212,3764,2295,
    3869,2437,3950,2515,3995,2538,4166,2559,4484,2280,4534,2255,4555,2260,4593,2382,
    4664,2491,4703,2671,4738,2754,4811,2862,4906,2935,4991,2942,5196,2877,5342,2869,
    5545,2782,5715,2808,5869,2810,5992,2832,6105,2891,6369,3082,6583,3116,6526,3203,
    6465,3242,6366,3340,6192,3414,5922,3457,5732,3576,5732,3618,5815,3727,5871,3833,
    5968,3921,6029,3944,6034,4000,6015,4043,5687,4191,4672,4806,4562,4838,3258,5475,
    3166,6035,3135,6398,3152,6425,polysep,6584,3115,6745,3059,6802,3054,6979,3053,
    7129,3089,polysep,7344,3139,7299,3158,7269,3150,polysep,6900,3306,6756,3397,
    6756,3436,polysep,7378,3441,7345,3474,7237,3513,polysep,7205,3512,7168,3544,
    7079,3578,7060,3603,polysep,7269,3580,7216,3601,7180,3701,polysep,7190,3649,
    7057,3648,6984,3678,polysep,7040,3578,7019,3607,6915,3653,6899,3679,polysep,
    6876,3658,6857,3682,6741,3734,6726,3758,polysep,6293,3755,6186,3833,6042,3901,
    polysep,6551,3798,6536,3822,6400,3893,polysep,6539,3862,6442,4793,polysep,
    6372,3879,6217,3970,polysep,6200,3948,6056,4046,polysep,6036,4078,6013,4615,
    polysep,7294,3867,7245,4069,7237,4346,polyend
    };
double pol1[]=
    {
    235,1853 ,485,2032 ,600,2091 ,682,2183 ,813,2414 ,914,2493 ,1051,2513,1390,2214,
    1421,2201,1495,2222,1522,2261,1541,2363,1609,2460,1680,2718,1750,2827,1830,2884,
    1917,2881,2091,2825,2223,2819,2399,2737,2489,2732,2895,2782,3080,2878,3193,2973,
    3301,3032,3426,3042,3614,3000,3890,2980,4027,3029,4073,3062,4089,3097,4082,3168,
    3788,3130,3660,3139,3548,3195,3409,3299,3307,3404,3112,3489,2860,3520,2732,3590,
    2720,3611,2728,3641,2796,3772,2907,3871,2903,3900,polysep,2908,3871,2968,3882,
    2984,3928,2991,3992,2954,4087,2638,4224,2203,4503,1588,4863,1479,4895,1184,5035,
    252,5489 ,235,5518 ,polysep,235,1912 ,257,1964 ,228,2035 ,polysep,258,1962 ,
    332,1963 ,polysep,2152,4342,2038,4436,1872,4528,polysep,1795,4616,1818,4568,
    1881,4574,polysep,1441,4864,1303,4904,927,5098 ,831,5141 ,767,5152 ,polysep,
    597,5017 ,669,4938 ,692,4942 ,polysep,838,4944 ,802,4981 ,855,5057 ,904,5054 ,
    polysep,843,5043 ,786,5062 ,795,5084 ,polysep,784,5063 ,732,5034 ,641,5086 ,
    637,5132 ,polysep,640,5086 ,581,5084 ,550,5107 ,585,5207 ,polysep,742,5031 ,
    760,4997 ,799,4981 ,polysep,1554,4604,1427,4654,polysep,1140,4622,1133,4647,
    1287,4669,1428,4634,polyend
    };
const int pnts0=(sizeof(pol0)/sizeof(pol0[0]))>>1;
const int pnts1=(sizeof(pol1)/sizeof(pol1[0]))>>1;
double da0[pnts0];  // delta angles of pol0
double da1[pnts1];  // delta angles of pol1
double M[16];       // align pol1 to pol0 matrix so pol0=M*pol1
double V[16];       // just GL view matrix so pol0,pol1 are fully visible
int a0=20,a1=30,b0=20,b1=30;    // match
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void compute_MV()
    {
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    int i,j,k;
    double x0,y0,x1,y1,x,y;
    double x2,y2,x3,y3;
    //--------------------------------------------------------
/*
    // reverse po1[] in case your polylines are in reverse in between pol0/pol1
    for (i=0,j=pnts1+pnts1-4;i<j;i+=2,j-=2)
        {
        x=pol1[i+0]; pol1[i+0]=pol1[j+0]; pol1[j+0]=x;
        y=pol1[i+1]; pol1[i+1]=pol1[j+1]; pol1[j+1]=y;
        }
    // rotate  po1[] to better test rotation correction
    x=5.0*deg; x0=cos(x); y0=sin(x);
    for (i=0;i<pnts1+pnts1;i+=2)
        {
        x=pol1[i+0];
        y=pol1[i+1];
        pol1[i+0]=+(x*x0)+(y*y0);
        pol1[i+1]=-(x*y0)+(y*x0);
        }
*/
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // M,V set to unit matrices
    for (i=0;i<16;i++) M[i]=0.0; for (i=0;i<16;i+=5) M[i]=1.0;
    for (i=0;i<16;i++) V[i]=0.0; for (i=0;i<16;i+=5) V[i]=1.0;
    // pol0 AABB
    x0=y0=+1e10;
    x1=y1=-1e10;
    for (i=0;;)
        {
        x=pol0[i]; i++;
        y=pol0[i]; i++;
        if (x>+1e10) break;
        if (x<-1e10) continue;
        if (x0>x) x0=x;
        if (x1<x) x1=x;
        if (y0>y) y0=y;
        if (y1<y) y1=y;
        }
    // pol0+pol1 AABB
    for (i=0;;)
        {
        x=pol1[i]; i++;
        y=pol1[i]; i++;
        if (x>+1e10) break;
        if (x<-1e10) continue;
        if (x0>x) x0=x;
        if (x1<x) x1=x;
        if (y0>y) y0=y;
        if (y1<y) y1=y;
        }
    // view V scale
    V[0] =+1.8/(x1-x0);
    V[5] =-1.8/(y1-y0);
    V[10]=+1.0;
    V[15]= 1.0;
    // view V offset
    V[12]=-0.5*(x1+x0)*V[0];
    V[13]=-0.5*(y1+y0)*V[5];
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // compute a0
    for (i=0,j=0,k=0;;k++)
        {
        da0[k]=0.0;
        x0=x1; x1=pol0[i]; i++;
        y0=y1; y1=pol0[i]; i++;
        if (!j){ x0=x1; y0=y1; } j++;
        if (x1>+1e10){ da0[k]=1000.0;       break;    }
        if (x1<-1e10){ da0[k]=1000.0;  j=0; continue; }
        da0[k]=atanxy(x1-x0,y1-y0);
        }
    // compute da0
    for (x1=0.0,i=0;i<pnts0;i++)
        {
        x0=x1; x1=da0[i]; i++;
        if (x1>999.0){ x1=0.0; continue; }
        x=x1-x0;
        while (x>+pi) x-=pi2;
        while (x<-pi) x+=pi2;
        da0[i]=x;
        }
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // compute a1
    for (i=0,j=0,k=0;;k++)
        {
        da1[k]=0.0;
        x0=x1; x1=pol1[i]; i++;
        y0=y1; y1=pol1[i]; i++;
        if (!j){ x0=x1; y0=y1; } j++;
        if (x1>+1e10){ da1[k]=1000.0;       break;    }
        if (x1<-1e10){ da1[k]=1000.0;  j=0; continue; }
        da1[k]=atanxy(x1-x0,y1-y0);
        }
    // compute da1
    for (x1=0.0,i=0;i<pnts1;i++)
        {
        x0=x1; x1=da1[i]; i++;
        if (x1>999.0){ x1=0.0; continue; }
        x=x1-x0;
        while (x>+pi) x-=pi2;
        while (x<-pi) x+=pi2;
        da1[i]=x;
        }
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // brute force window search ignoring separators
    int n=15;   // search window size
    a0=-1; b0=-1; x1=-1.0;
    for (i=0;i<pnts0-n;i++)
     for (j=0;j<pnts1-n;j++)
        {
        for (x0=0.0,k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
            y0=da0[i+k]; if (y0>999.0) break;
            y1=da1[j+k]; if (y1>999.0) break;
            x0+=fabs(y1-y0);
            }
        if (k<n) continue;  // skip shorter polylines
        x0/=n;
        if ((a0<0)||(x1>x0)){ x1=x0; a0=i; b0=j; }
        }
    a1=a0+n; b1=b0+n;
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // line0
    i=a0+a0;
    x0=pol0[i]; i++;
    y0=pol0[i]; i++;
    i=a1+a1;
    x1=pol0[i]; i++;
    y1=pol0[i]; i++;
    // line1
    i=b0+b0;
    x2=pol1[i]; i++;
    y2=pol1[i]; i++;
    i=b1+b1;
    x3=pol1[i]; i++;
    y3=pol1[i]; i++;
    // trasform
    x=sqrt(((x1-x0)*(x1-x0))+((y1-y0)*(y1-y0)));
    y=sqrt(((x3-x2)*(x3-x2))+((y3-y2)*(y3-y2)));
    double scale=x/y;
    double ang=atanxy(x1-x0,y1-y0)-atanxy(x3-x2,y3-y2);
    M[0]=+scale*cos(ang);
    M[1]=+scale*sin(ang);
    M[4]=-scale*sin(ang);
    M[5]=+scale*cos(ang);
    // offset (x,y,?) = M*(x2,y2,0.0,1.0)
    x=(M[0]*x2)+(M[4]*y2);
    y=(M[1]*x2)+(M[5]*y2);
    M[12]=x0-x;
    M[13]=y0-y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()      // main rendering code
    {
    int i,j;
    double x,y,r;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glLoadMatrixd(V);

    // render pol0 (purple)
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (i=0;;)
        {
        if        (i==a0+a0)  glColor3f(0.2,0.4,0.8);
        if ((!i)||(i==a1+a1)) glColor3f(0.8,0.0,0.6);
        x=pol0[i]; i++;
        y=pol0[i]; i++;
        if (x>+1e10) break;
        if (x<-1e10){ glEnd(); glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); continue; }
        glVertex2d(x,y);
        }
    glEnd();
    // render a0 start point (yellow)
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0); r=100.0;
    x=pol0[a0+a0  ];
    y=pol0[a0+a0+1];
    glVertex2d(x-r,y-r);
    glVertex2d(x+r,y+r);
    glVertex2d(x+r,y-r);
    glVertex2d(x-r,y+r);
    glEnd();

    for (j=0;j<2;j++)   // render pol1 twice
        {
        if (j)
            {
            // apply M matrix to view on second pass (align)
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glMultMatrixd(M);
            }

        // render pol1 (white)
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (i=0;;)
            {
            if        (i==b0+b0)  glColor3f(0.2,0.9,0.2);
            if ((!i)||(i==b1+b1)) glColor3f(0.7,0.7,0.7);
            x=pol1[i]; i++;
            y=pol1[i]; i++;
            if (x>+1e10) break;
            if (x<-1e10){ glEnd(); glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); continue; }
            glVertex2d(x,y);
            }
        glEnd();

        // render b0 start point (yellow)
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0); r=100.0;
        x=pol1[b0+b0  ];
        y=pol1[b0+b0+1];
        glVertex2d(x-r,y-r);
        glVertex2d(x+r,y+r);
        glVertex2d(x+r,y-r);
        glVertex2d(x-r,y+r);
        glEnd();
        }

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // application init
    gl_init(Handle);
    compute_MV();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // application exit
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // window resize
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // window repaint
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just ignore the VCL stuff... The important thing is `compute_MV()` function which computes `M,V` matrices. M is your aligning transform and `V` is just view transform to `<-1,+1>` range.

The `atanxy(x,y)` is my own function but its the same as `atan2(y,x)` which is common math function however that one needs to handle edge cases when x or y is zero otherwise exception might be thrown (that is what my [atanxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214) does).

Used OpenGL matrix math is described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075743/how-do-i-compose-a-rotation-matrix-with-human-readable-angles-from-scratch/28084380?s=1%7C66.4973#28084380) and OpenGL stuff is in my [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

**Here preview of result**

[image: result]

The `pol0[]` is in purple and `pol1[]` is in white twice once in raw state and second is aligned to `pol0[]`. The code is far from perfect and the search would need much more tweaking but I think its a good start point.

The search itself simply check constant size `n` window in both polylines and compute the abs difference between their `delta angles` and remembers the smallest distance positions ... Even if it is `O(n.pnts0*pnts1)` its pretty fast (less than 0.2 sec on my machine) ...

There is a lot of room for improvement like you do not need to step both polylines by single point its enough that just one loop is stepping by one point and the other might step by half or full window size... You can test for more window sizes... you can tweak the comparison and much more ...

**In case your data is not sampled with the same average distance between points you should resample your data to common segment size first!**

Comment: Wow.. nicely detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinPerry Also its a good idea to align the data to peaks while resampling to avoid aliasing errors while comparing... Another option would be to do sliding average of the `da0,da1` after or `pol0,pol1` before `da` computation. That could also eliminate the problem of unaligned sampling ... Also you can speed up the brute force window loops to start from peaks instead of trying every position... btw very interesting question I am surprised it did not achieve bigger attentions from hi-rep users from the field probably a slight retag would help adding `[math]` and `[vector]` tags